# Grep specific paragraph of command output in Linux

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to parse `iostat -x 1 2` command's output to monitor remote computer from my java application.

This is the output:

```
Linux 2.6.39-400.126.1.el5uek (abcprod.abc-en.local)         02/27/2014

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.57    0.00    0.87    0.01    0.00   96.56

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    54.24  0.35 10.64     6.95   518.97    47.89     0.01    1.06   0.19   0.21
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    68.40     0.00    2.08   0.94   0.00
sda2              0.00    54.23  0.35 10.64     6.94   518.97    47.89     0.01    1.06   0.19   0.21
dm-0              0.00     0.00  0.18 48.77     4.18   390.19     8.06     0.08    1.63   0.02   0.10
dm-1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     8.00     0.00    1.06   0.18   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     8.00     0.00    1.78   0.14   0.00
dm-3              0.00     0.00  0.17 16.10     2.76   128.78     8.09     0.03    2.10   0.07   0.11

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          11.61    0.00    3.20    0.00    0.00   85.19

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   191.00  0.00 43.00     0.00  1872.00    43.53     0.00    0.09   0.05   0.20
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00   191.00  0.00 43.00     0.00  1872.00    43.53     0.00    0.09   0.05   0.20
dm-0              0.00     0.00  0.00 234.00     0.00  1872.00     8.00     0.00    0.02   0.01   0.20
dm-1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

I only need the second part of the output(beginning from fourth paragraph):

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          11.61    0.00    3.20    0.00    0.00   85.19

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   191.00  0.00 43.00     0.00  1872.00    43.53     0.00    0.09   0.05   0.20
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00   191.00  0.00 43.00     0.00  1872.00    43.53     0.00    0.09   0.05   0.20
dm-0              0.00     0.00  0.00 234.00     0.00  1872.00     8.00     0.00    0.02   0.01   0.20
dm-1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not how to use `grep` to do it, but you can use `perl`:

```
iostat -x 1 2 | perl -e 'local $/=""; @p=<STDIN>; print @p[3,4];'
```

---

Some explanations:

1. `local`, see [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local())

   > A `local` modifies its listed variables to be "local" to the enclosing block, `eval`, or `do FILE` --and **to any subroutine called from within that block**. A `local` just gives temporary values to global (meaning package) variables.
2. `$/`, see [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

   > The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is.

Comment: That solves the problem. What does this "local" parameter do?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of the lines for the first paragraph is fixed you can use `sed` like this

`iostat -x 1 2 | sed 'N,$!d'` - where `N` is the number of the lines of first paragraph

Comment: +1 for temporary solution. But when there is more devices, this code won't work right?

Comment: Yes, somehow you have to figure out the number of the devices first